# Checking a specific value in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to find if a specific value is present in a table. for ex below is my table

```
EmpID   ApplID  Status
123456  1       complete
789365  2       Requested
```

Note: MS sqlserver

I am trying the below query

```
Select Status from ApplicationRequest where Like %Requested% ;
```

The query should return true if the value exist and false if value does not exist

Answer (score 2):

If you use:

```
where status Like '%Requested%'
```

like that, you will never get `'False'` since if there are no rows containing `'Requested'` in `status`, then the result will be empty.
So use it with `EXISTS`:

```
select 
  case 
    when exists (select 1 from ApplicationRequest where status Like '%Requested%') then 'TRUE' 
    else 'FALSE' 
  end result
```

Answer (score 0):

Use aggregation and a `case` expression:

```
select (case when count(*) > 0 then 'true' else 'false' end)
from ApplicationRequest
where status Like %Requested% ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Status='Requested' THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END AS STATUS
FROM ApplicationRequest 
WHERE LIKE 'Requested'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the specific value then following is outputted query:

```
SELECT 
CASE 
    WHEN COUNT(*) > 0   THEN 'TRUE' 
    ELSE 'FALSE'
END AS RESULT
FROM ApplicationRequest 
WHERE Status like '%Requested%'
```

[image]

Dynamic output

```
SELECT 
CASE 
    WHEN COUNT(*) > 0   THEN 'TRUE' 
    ELSE 'FALSE'
END AS RESULT
FROM Table name
WHERE Column_name like '%SearchValue%'
```